# Selenium Automation : Getting Error In Explicit Method

Tags: selenium, ui-automation

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Syncrnization {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\\\chromedriver_win32 (3)\\\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://compelapps.in/eFacilito_Control_Center/Login");
    
    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));

    sendKeys(driver , username , 10 , "mansoor.a");
    
    }
    public static void sendKeys(WebDriver driver , WebElement element , int timeout , String value )
    {
        new WebDriverWait(driver , timeout).
        until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        element.sendKeys(value);
    }

}
```

code Showing The Error To Change timeout Into Duration
new WebDriverWait(driver , timeout). : In This Line
If I Am Doing So ..
It Gives Error In
sendKeys(driver , username , 10 , "mansoor.a"); : In This Line In SendKey ..

Comment: What error do you get? Can you paste it?

Comment: Change type of 'timeout' to 'Duration'

Comment: If i Changing Timeout to duration It Give Error In Sendkey Where i have Passed The Values : To Change method Or create Method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the time out in WebDriverWait like, for ex.,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

Instead, you have to mention like below:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
```

For implicit wait also, you have to mention like:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
```

Comment: Actually My Another Friend Pasted The Exact Same Code In His IDC It Working Fine Butr Not Working In My IDE I dont Why